# Is the malicious botting, how to prevent?

Tags: apache, security

I recently set up a subdomain on my website with the intention to soon clone my website for testing purposes. Subdomain was "beta", so beta.example.com

It was set up and password protected via htaccess and is directed through Cloudflare, it's about three days old and was never announced publicly (only I know of it).

Today I notice this on my Apache Server Stats page:
[image]

Also, CPU load was increasing and very, very high. Upon refreshing, this continued and is actually still continuing right now. Is this some sort of botting/brute force attack? I can't imagine how/why else so many IPs would be accessing this unlinked/private subdomain. I've since taken it down from Cloudflare DNS and the IPs are still connecting somehow, I assume it will take time for it to propagate.

Is this malicious? And how can it be prevented? I assume it was/is attempting to brute force the htaccess password? Is it because it's a common subdomain name? ("beta") - would it matter? Again, it's only been about three days so damn they work fast.

Answer (score 0):

It can be search engine robots, It can be script kiddies, It can be brute force, you can have more information in your log file or by analyzing IP address.

I'm not sure to really understand your problem and what you want.

If you website is online, so yes some people/bots/robots will try to access to it, like any other website.

If you don't want than anybody access to your website, you can add an IP restriction.

Comment: Well like I said, this is a subdomain I just added. *nobody* knows about it and not 1 link to it exists on the internet, yet here are dozens and dozens of IPs hitting it every minute? I've since removed the CNAME DNS record from Cloudflare but they persist. Point is, I'm wondering if this is malicious and if so how to stop it? I've taken the domain "offline" so to speak but the hits remain? Seems impossible. I'm trying to rule it out as a coincidence or role in the current high CPU usage of the site.

Comment: Also, these do not appear in log when running `sudo tail -100 /etc/httpd/logs/access_log`

Comment: It's a new hosting ? It's possible than some bots, robots or scrips are trying to access to your server because the IP address was used for a high traffic website, or for streaming, for for something like that.

What about the state of connections (ESTAB, TIME_WAIT, SYN_RECV, ...) when you look (netstat) ?